# Ruby/Rails document generator: How to convert the HTML to PDF

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, documentation, rdoc, yard

I am using YARD gem with my Ruby code. 
1: How can I use the `yardoc -query <QUERY>` to create a document that has all classes which contain a particular method.
2: `yardoc  --one-file`  ->  Generates output as a single file (.html)
This file contains all classes and methods but when I used WickedPdf Gem to convert this html to PDF, I am just left with method definitions but not details (in html, this is viewed by clicking on 'view source' or the method name)

I tried the same with rdoc and facing the same issue